# horizontal pager with vertical pager. How can we apply?

Tags: java, android

If any one has answer for this question please comment me.

[Vertical-Pager](https://github.com/grantland/android-verticalpager/tree/be106911947e3dddb6522dbadb4029cea32bd91e)

[Horizontal-Pager](https://github.com/grantland/android-horizontalpager)

So please check this two projects. I just want to implement both in only one class so I can scroll both side with only one class.

Answer (score 0):

I know for a fact that the Horizontal Pager class supports Vertical scrolling, so I believe you can nest them. Add code to the Horizontal Paging class that can detect Vertical Paging.

Or,

you could add a ScrollView to every child from the ViewGroup inside the Horizontal Pager.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Yes I am trying to add scrollview for each child but that is not good and not to show that way. Because design was not properly arrange. So I just want to when user scrolling vertical so all of that child must be scrolling in vertically and same as horizontally. Is it possible????

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean, so you want to Scroll vertically or Page vertically? Because I found how to Scroll Vertically inside the Horizontal Pager but I haven't found how to Page yet

Comment: You simply create an instance of Horizontalpager, and then, create a scrollview, inside the scrollview you create your layout, then at the end, you add the scrollview as a child view to the Pager.

Comment: See, my layout contains 3 parts. 1.TopBar 2.HorizontalPager 3.Bottombar. In HorizontalPager contains only Linearlayout. Becoz I want to add child into HorizontalPager using Dyanmic way(at run time). Lets take an example. I have add 5 view dynamic like this way. ImageView1-ImageView2-ImageView3-ImageView4-ImageView5. Means all child are Imageviews. Now My question is how can I scroll vertically for all those 5 ImageView at same time. Currently It is working but each ImageView hv vertical scroll view. But I want to only one vertical scrollview and that scrollview contains those all 5 ImageView.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to have 5 ImageViews on the same page and scroll vertically on that page?? What's the point in the Horizontal Pager then? You can create a ScrollView, containing 1 linlayout child, with 5 imageview children, and add the scrollview to the HorizontalPager. it's easy to do in a loop.